# No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page Delphi 11 TRestRequest, TRestClient

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

When performing a query on a uri I receive the error:

> No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte.

The error occurs on the following line:

```
FClient.HTTPClient.Response.ContentAsString(LEncoding)
```

I'm using `FallbackCharsetEncoding` as UTF-8, but I still receive the error. When consulting the uri through postman, a valid JSON is returned.

Can anyone help me? I don't know if the problem is in the component that performs the conversion to UTF-8, or if it's actually something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try and post code that reproduces the problem instead of one isolated line.

Comment: You know that there is a [TRESTResponse](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/REST.Client.TRESTResponse)  for handling responses from the request?